# merge two regular expression in validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have these two expressions:

```
[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*
```

or

```
[اآبپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی\s]+$
```

I want to use them in expression validator and I don't know how to merge them.

Actually I need validator to valid just these two expressions or any combination of them.

I have tested `|` too.

Comment: These regexes are mutually exclusive (aside from the `\s`). What do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: @Blender I want an expression to validate both.

Comment: @user1181065: As in a single expression that does one or the other?

Comment: @JaredC No...Actually the first expression is for validate english alphabets and the second is for persian alphabets.I need to validate persian and english characters.

Comment: So does it not work to just combine the two character sets into a single large one `[<english><persian>]+`?